# How to display bootstrap selectpicker in center not text?

Tags: html, css, select, html-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap selectpicker.I have to display selectpicker select drop down in center of the popup but I don't want to center the text inside the select drop down.I am able to display the button but not select drop down.Would you help me in this?

```css
/*end menu*/
.login-section{
background-color: #fff; 
  border-radius: 04px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
   height: 290px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -150px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
box-shadow:         1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);  
}

  select
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
input[type="submit"], select{
  display: block;
  padding: 07px 02px;
  margin: 07px auto;
  border-radius: 04px;
  width: 250px;

}

input[type="submit"]
{
  background-color: #773F9B;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:18px;
border-radius: 04px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="login-section">
   <select class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" name="test1" >
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>
<select  name="test2">
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>

      <select class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" name="test3" >
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `padding: 10px 20px;` and removed `width: 295px` in your `.login-section`;

Try this.

```css
/*end menu*/
.login-section{
  padding: 10px 20px;
background-color: #fff; 
  border-radius: 04px;
   height: 290px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -150px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
box-shadow:         1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);  
}

select
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
input[type="submit"], select{
  display: block;
  padding: 07px 02px;
  margin: 7px auto;
  border-radius: 04px;
  width: 250px;

}

input[type="submit"]
{
  background-color: #773F9B;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:18px;
border-radius: 04px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="login-section">
   <select class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" name="test1" >
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>
<select  name="test2">
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>

      <select class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" name="test3" >
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Jyothi, Working for me but if I am adding <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script> drop down showing different

Comment: What's the difference you are facing?

Comment: But it's working fine for the same `src` of bootstrap as in example snippet. Can you reproduce the same here?

Comment: Second drop down is display proper because of i haven't added class selectpicker

Answer (score 0):

Put the selects inside a `<div>` and center it with css:
 - fixed size
 - left and right margins auto

```css
/*end menu*/
.login-section{
background-color: #fff; 
  border-radius: 04px;
  width: 295px;
   height: 290px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -150px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
box-shadow:         1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);  
}

select
{
  margin: 10px;
}
input[type="submit"], select{
  display: block;
  padding: 07px 02px;
  margin: 07px auto;
  border-radius: 04px;
  width: 250px;

}

input[type="submit"]
{
  background-color: #773F9B;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:18px;
border-radius: 04px;
}
#select-cont {
   width:250px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="login-section">
   <div id="select-cont">
       <select class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" name="test1" >
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>
<select  name="test2">
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>

      <select class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" name="test3" >
       <option>Select</option>
       <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
     <option>abc</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
select
{
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Roy, I tried that also but Still same issue

Comment: @PeterHall A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @FelixSFD This answer will only fix the issue for the user who posted the question, and overlaps with other answers. A good answer would explain _why_ this works, so that other users can find it and benefit too.  However, I've read the post you linked to, and I agree with you. I's a UX problem with the review queue because no one wants to click "Looks OK" when they don't think the post is OK.